# How to debug command Line Dataloader error

Tags: data-loader

We have been using command line data loader for the data migration to salesforce. Recently I have the updated the security token for the API user which we are using for the migration from the insertion to salesforce has been stopped. Do I need to update my config files since I have security token change? . If I have to update the config files with the security token what is the procedure? The password has not been changed only the security token is reset. Where I can see the exact error since the insert has not been made to salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

As security token is updated,
you will have to encrypt the password (password + security token) and have to update the config file with encrypted password.

The link below will give some idea on configuration required-

[Automating data loader](https://ilovesfdc.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/automating-dataloader)

Hope this helps..